# Test if a Procedure Throws an Exception in DUnitX

Tags: delphi

I am working with the DUnitX framework, and am trying to test if the procedure throws an exception.

Currently I have the following test procedure:

```
procedure TAlarmDataTest.TestIdThrowsExceptionUnderFlow;
begin
  Input := 0;
  Assert.WillRaise(Data.GetId(input), IdIsZeroException, 'ID uninitialized');
end;
```

When I go to compile I get an error 'There is no overloaded version of 'WillRaise' that can be called with these arguments.'

Is there a better way to check if the procedure is raising a custom exception, or should I use a try, except block that passes if the exception is caught?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first parameter of `WillRaise` is `TTestLocalMethod`. That is declared as:

```
type
  TTestLocalMethod = reference to procedure;
```

In other words, you are meant to pass a procedure that `WillRaise` can call. You are not doing that. You are calling the procedure. Do it like this:

```
Assert.WillRaise(
  procedure begin Data.GetId(input); end,
  IdIsZeroException, 
  'ID uninitialized'
);
```

The point being that `WillRaise` needs to invoke the code that is expected to raise. If you invoke the code then the exception will be raised whilst preparing the parameters to be passed to `WillRaise`. So, we need to postpone execution of the code that is expected to raise until we are inside `WillRaise`. Wrapping the code inside an anonymous method is one simple way to achieve that.

For what it is worth, the implementation of `WillRaise` looks like this:

```
class procedure Assert.WillRaise(const AMethod : TTestLocalMethod; 
  const exceptionClass : ExceptClass; const msg : string);
begin
  try
    AMethod;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      CheckExceptionClass(e, exceptionClass);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Fail('Method did not throw any exceptions.' + AddLineBreak(msg), 
    ReturnAddress);
end;
```

So, `WillRaise` wraps the call to your procedure in a try/except block, and fails if the desired exception is not raised.

If you are still struggling with understanding this then I suspect you need to brush up your knowledge of [anonymous methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi). Once you get on top of that I'm sure it will be obvious.

Comment: This is just checks the raising of the exception. But what about the parameters? Is the exception created with x value in the y parameter, etc?

Comment: Read the source code and documentation for DUnitX. Look at the various WillRaiseXXX methods.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I find the one matching to my needs.